# GCP Backup for GKE error: "Backup autofail because cluster agent is nonresponsive (misconfigured?)"

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm trying to use the GCP Backup for GKE service, but I'm getting some errors. From the documentation I need a GKE clusters running version 1.24 or higher. My version is 1.24.10-gke.2300.
When I try to do a backup after a one hour, the job fails and I see the error "Backup autofail because cluster agent is nonresponsive (misconfigured?)".

I have tried to look the logs of the gkebackup-agent-0 pod by running `kubectl --namespace gkebackup logs -f gkebackup-agent-0`

and what I'm getting is:

```
> controller="backupjob" controllerGroup="gkebackup.gke.io" controllerKind="BackupJob" BackupJob="first-backup-ever-a99bdeee-0943-4a3e-aa64-a65067a6886a" namespace="" name="first-backup-ever-a99bdeee-0943-4a3e-aa64-a65067a6886a" reconcileID=6f200b9d-091c-4091-bc7c-d944e6aa82cb
E0525 14:08:43.954927       1 controller.go:326] "Reconciler error" err=<
        googleapi: Error 403: Request had insufficient authentication scopes.
        Details:
        [
          {
            "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
            "domain": "googleapis.com",
            "metadata": {
              "method": "google.cloud.gkebackup.v1agent.BackupForGKE.GetBackup",
              "service": "gkebackup.googleapis.com"
            },
            "reason": "ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE_INSUFFICIENT"
          }
        ]

        More details:
        Reason: insufficientPermissions, Message: Insufficient Permission
```

It's obviously a permissions problem, but can somebody help me fix it?

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You may try temporarily turning off [Domain Restriction](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/organization-policy/restricting-domains)

1. You can try to remove the organization policy containing the Domain
   Restriction constraint.
2. Then apply the role to your user / service account.
3. Then implement the organization policy with the Domain Restriction
   constraint again.